# How to properly align form?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a form with a format of:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>TextView EditText Button</RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>TextView EditText Button</RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>TextView EditText Button</RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>TextView EditText Button</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have aligned the TextView to parentLeft, the Button to parentRight. And so far, the EditText to toLeftOf Button. Now, I want the EditText to all line up with the longest TextView, however I can't seem to use toRightOf of a TextView from a different layout. I'm not even sure that's the best way to do it.

What is the proper way to get everything to line up straight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `TableLayout` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing the `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayoutand` and remove the `RelativeLayout` for each row or use `TableLayout`  as asahi suggested.